# Memory keep increasing when the UITableView scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory

there is a strange problem I have not met ever

there is an array() including some custom object named MyClass parsed by JSONKit;

when I keep scrolling the tableview the memory will keeping increasing too.

but when replace

```
cell.textLabel.text = myclass.name;
```

with

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"cool";
```

or

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"a-%d", indexPath.row];
```

it's ok  the memory with keep stable

but if I use

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"a-%@-i",myclass.name, indexPath.row];
```

it also keep increasing;

It will drive my crazy!!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Singers";
    OMTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    MyClass *myclass = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[[OMTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];   
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = myclass.name;

    return cell;
}
```

MyClass

there is two class one Base another inherit

Base:

```
@interface OMBase : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *data;
    NSString *name;
    NSArray *keys;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *data;

@implementation OMBase

@synthesize data, name;


- (void)setData:(NSMutableDictionary *)adata{
    if (data){
        [data release];
        data = nil;
    }
    data = [adata mutableCopy];
}

- (void)dealloc{
    if (keys){
        [keys release];
    }
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)init{
    if (self = [super init]){
        self.data = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}
```

inherit:

```
#import "OMBase.h"

@interface OMLyric : OMBase

- (NSString *)songid;
- (NSString *)content;

#import "OMLyric.h"

@implementation OMLyric

- (NSString *)songid{
    return [data objectForKey:@"songid"];
}

- (NSString *)content{
    return [data objectForKey:@"content"];
}
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `cell.textLabel.text = ((MyClass *)self.data[indexPath.row]).name;` instead of `cell.textLabel.text = myclass.name;` ?

Comment: what have u written in `-(NSString*)getName` ?

Comment: yeah It still keeping increasing @MarkoNikolovski

Comment: How much does it increase? put some more code and make sure you are using device not simulator for profiling.

Comment: are you sure that your cells are correctly reused? Is the identifiers you use in your custom cell equal as the one that you use in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @Tarek I am using device~ :) and it keep increasing before all cell has been shown one time

Comment: @elio.d I am sure the cell is reused the dealloc method only called for few times

Comment: actually to verify if are reused you either put a log inside the if in cellForRowAtindexPath and see how many times the message is logged or suing instruments have a look at how many objects of your cell type are allocated

Comment: @elio.d that's right :) but I am sure the cell reused

Comment: What if you do `[myclass release]` before you do `return cell`?

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski thx, maybe I cant do that, because myclass is store in a array and when the array dealloc I think the app will be crashed~ :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `myclass.name` getter returns a new allocated object. We can't say more without seeing `myclass`.